# Long email address with bottom straight line responsive issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am facing a strange issue and need help on this.
if i keep space in email address-

```
<h3>
    Not sure where to start?<br>
    Reach us as at <a href="mailto:contact@superadminconsult.com">contact @superadminconsult. com</a>
</h3>
```

**Output** is ok-

[image]

But when I write full email address like this

```
<h3>
    Not sure where to start?<br>
    Reach us as at <a href="mailto:contact@superadminconsult.com">contact@superadminconsult.com</a>
</h3>
```

**Output**

[image]

Any kind of help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please remove extra `</a>` tag

Comment: I removed but result is same

Comment: use ` word-break: break-all;` to `a` tag

Comment: One more question I have ::after with <a> in css and it contains a straight line bottom of email address. Is it possible to keep that line after break the email address?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221722/discussion-between-abdullah-al-noor-and-hakik-zaman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

source [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break)

```
  a{
    word-break: break-all;
    }
```